# What is the result of deviating from the Kelvin layout when designing a current sensing PCB?

Tags: pwm, current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor, inrush-current

For a two terminal current sensing shunt resistor with a layout that deviates from the symmetric Kelvin layout, what results should be expected?

For example, with this layout, what result would be expected on the sense leads when the resistor is subject to a 3A current?

[image]

Comment: It is possible that a slight asymmetry would matter less than the (apparent) lack of bypassing on the opamp + thin long GND/VCC traces.

Comment: Is it for measuring the current draw of a BLDC motor? If so then results will probably be practically indistinguishable from a perfect Kelvin connection.

Comment: I'd expect that the Q# side main terminal layout MIGHT have significant effect. . Does the major current come from left or right or straight down? How does that effect voltage profile across the pad. You MAY be able to measure voltage profiles across the top of the tab (uVs) if there is asymmetry.  The Kelvin connection assumes that mid pad on the inner surface represents the average pad voltage. As shown it may not as much due to main current flow as to sense connections..

Comment: @Wesley Lee, What recommendations would you make for this as far as bypassing?

Comment: Bruce Abbott, Yes.
@Russell McMahon, The current flows from 'V_Power' to the junction (under "Q3"), then splits off to the three high side MOSFETs. Measuring the Vdrop across the resistor with two scope probes showed an abnormally high voltage drop for the current flowing. It was noted by another commenter that that separate scope probes may not be synchronized enough to be accurate to the 50mV measured, tho.

Answer (score 3):

You should take the opportunity to route your sense traces so that they are as close to the same length and symmetrical as possible. Here is a mockup of what I am suggesting.

[image]

You almost want to consider the routing of these sense lines as a controlled impedance pair. The goal to be that both lines share the same common mode voltage coupling from other circuits and external influences.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have perfect symmetry.

I'd flatten that lower right region just to right of "4", and achieve total balance.

To simulate the effects, build a grid of 2_D resistors that includes that 45_degree piece; use 0.000498 ohms (that is 500 microOhms) per square.

Then you need to include the 3rd dimension of the resistor's solder terminal.

Comment: I'm still curious why the Kelvin traces are offset

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question of "what is the effect of asymmetry"; while it's good advice, I am curious as well just what effects it would have and why (and how much) the symmetry matters in a kelvin sense connection.

Comment: @DKNguyen, Lack of experience mainly. There is a via in the way (not shown in the img), but that could have been moved. I'm a mechanical, so PCB design is still an ongoing learning experience for me...